# Setting a Title in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using iOS 5 with storyboards. I have a root `Navigation Controller` and attached to that a `Tab Bar Controller` with two `Tab Bar` Items. I'm trying to manually or programmatically set the title in one of the `Tab Bar` items on the top navigation bar.

Below are some of the fun things I tried in `ViewDidLoad` but the title is still not showing up.

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"Item List";
self.navigationItem.title = @"Item List";
self.tabBarItem.title = @"Item List";
[self.tabBarItem setTitle: @"Item List"];
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Item List"];
[[self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle: @"Item List"];
```

How do you set the title in iOS 5?

Comment: Also a good read: How do I accept answers on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4):

Did you try self.title = @"Item List"? :)

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Item List";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it both in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillLoad but the title still doesn't show for some reason...

Comment: It might be related to the fact that my Tab Bar item is loading a UIWebView.

Comment: that shouldn't matter. Can you validate that 1) you've properly set the viewControllers property of the uitabbar in IB and 2) you are setting self.title inside -(void) viewDidLoad of the viewController. If you are, put a breakpoint inside viewDidLoad to make sure its getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments. I found the correct statement is

self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"Item List";

called in ViewDidLoad.